# How to use would have + past participle without conditionals

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, aspect

I've come across many sentences that contains **would have + past participle**, I know how to use it in conditionals sentences but my problem is how to use it without conditionals sentences

For example , I heard this sentence in a movie

> Have you ever think about how I would have felt?

So What is the difference between saying,

- Have you ever thought about how I would have felt?

and

- Have you ever thought about how I felt ?

Comment: "Have you ever think" is not grammatically correct to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrong,it's (have you ever thought about how i would have felt?

Comment: I see. To me, the first one implies a hypothetical statement, but the second one talks about an actual thing that happened and made him/her to feel in a certain way. Not sure though!

Answer (score 1):

- "How I would have felt" is conditional. There is an "if" clause, in the past, implied in this question. For example, "Have you ever thought about how I would have felt *if you had moved to Australia*?"
- "How I felt" refers to something that actually happened in the past. "Have you ever thought about how I felt *when you moved to Australia*?"